# curl command different from curl assigned to variable, in bash

Tags: bash, curl

I'm getting a slightly different result when I run curl as a command than when I put its output in a variable and then read said variable.

1

```
x=`curl http://www.movies.com/rss-feeds/top-ten-box-office-rss 2> /dev/null`; echo $x
```

2

```
curl http://www.movies.com/rss-feeds/top-ten-box-office-rss 2> /dev/null
```

The differences between them are that when I do 2, I get everything and it is all formatted, and that, when I use option 1, besides being all one block, I miss all of the following (for each movie):

```
<pubDate>Tue, 04 Mar 2014 08:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
      <source url="http://www.movies.com">Movies.com Top 10 Box Office</source>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title><![CDATA[10. Ride Along - $2.0M]]></title>
```

I saw a similar question here ([In ShellScript Assign Variable Based on Curl Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418505/in-shellscript-assign-variable-based-on-curl-output)), but when I tried the proposed solution I get the same difference. Reading (and trying) flags doesn't help.

Apologies for the really beginner question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
echo "$x"
```

to prevent word-splitting of `$x`.

In general, you should quote variables unless you know that they don't contain whitespace or wildcards, or you explicitly want those characters to be processed.

Answer (score 1):

With `echo $x` (version 1), the contents of `x` are placed on the command line as arguments to `echo` and interpreted according to shell rules, and then echoed to the terminal.  Use `echo "$x"` to prevent this.

With that one change, the two methods will produce output that is differs only by one character:  the final newline.  That character is removed by the shell when processing backticks.  `man bash` documents this:

> Bash performs the expansion  by  executing  command  and
>          replacing  the  command  substitution  with the standard
>          output  of  the  command,  with  any  trailing  newlines
>          deleted.   Embedded  newlines  are not deleted, but they
>          may be removed during word splitting.